# The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a basic layout with a constraintlayout and a textview using Android Studio 3 Canary 4 and newest version of Gradle 4

SDK : 26

supportLibrary: 26.0.0-beta2

> gradle

```
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

> layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextureView
      android:id="@+id/textureView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="190dp"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="232dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> styles.xml

```
  <style name="AppThemeWhite" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main_color_500</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/main_color_500</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppThemeWhite.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay.white" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
  </style>

  <!-- ToolBar -->
  <style name="ToolBaWhiterStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
```

> v21/styles.xml

```
   <resources>

  <style name="AppThemeWhite" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppThemeWhite.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Error :

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.
>
> Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ConstraintLayout_Layout
>     at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:440)
>     at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.(ConstraintLayout.java:420)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. There is an issue with support library `26.0.0-beta2`. Downgrading to `26.0.0-beta1` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've been trying to get my Android Studio renderer to display ContraintLayout for the past 2 days. Searching for solutions had be importing various packages, dependencies, and updating everything.

The [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44841512/2350083) actually fixed the problem.

In order to implement the rollback, go to File -> Project Structure
Click on Dependencies, remove the AppCompat that is there.
Press the + sign and add library.
Search for "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1"
Resync and rebuild.